# How can i edit a package.json with postinstall

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, npm-scripts, post-install

I have created a package on npm that create a "scss directory stucture" and I would like to copy/add custom scripts to the package.json file at the root of the project.

```sh
MY-PROJECT
├── node_modules
├── scss
└── package.json <--
```

All I was able to do, is to copy a file name "package.json" to the local directory but if there is already one, it will overwrite it.

Obvisously i do not want to overwrite that file, but only add scripts like "npm run watch". So the user would be able to start working on its project right away without having to write those scripts himself.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize the following node.js script:

**post-install.js**

```js
const saveFile = require('fs').writeFileSync;

const pkgJsonPath = require.main.paths[0].split('node_modules')[0] + 'package.json';

const json = require(pkgJsonPath);

if (!json.hasOwnProperty('scripts')) {
  json.scripts = {};
}

json.scripts['watch'] = '<some_commands_here>';

saveFile(pkgJsonPath, JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
```

**package.json**

In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* define your `postinstall` script as follows:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node post-install"
  }
}
```

<sub>**Note:** The npm script (above) assumes `post-install.js` resides in the same directory as your `package.json` file.</sub>

---

**Explanation:**

1. In the line of code that reads:

   ```
   const pkgJsonPath = require.main.paths[0].split('node_modules')[0] + 'package.json'
   ```

   we obtain the path to the *package.json* for the project that is consuming your npm package and assign it to the `pkgJsonPath` variable.

   - [`require.main.paths`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_main) returns an Array of pathnames.
   - We obtain the pathname at index `0` and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it using `node_modules` as the separator.
   - The resultant array element at index `0` gives us the pathname of the project directory, (i.e. the pathname of the project that is consuming your npm package).
   - Finally the `package.json` string is concatenated using the plus operator (`+`).
2. Next we `require` the *package.json* file and assign the parsed JSON to the `json` variable.
3. We then check whether the *package.json* has a `scripts` key, and if it doesn't we create an a new `scripts` property/key and assign it an empty object, i.e.

   ```js
   if (!json.hasOwnProperty('scripts')) {
     json.scripts = {};
   }
   ```
4. The following part is where we define the custom npm script to be added to the *package.json* file -  you'll need to change this part as necessary:

   ```js
   json.scripts['watch'] = '<some_commands_here>';
   ```
5. Finally we [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the `json` object and overwrite the original *package.json* file with the new data using [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options).

Answer (score 2):

You can write small script and add command in scripts or modify `package.json`

**script.js**

```
const json = require("./package.json")
json.scripts["run:watch"] = "npm run watch"
require("fs").writeFileSync(process.cwd() + "/package.json", JSON.stringify(json, null, 2))
```

**package.json**

```
{
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node script.js"
  }
}
```

You can also write sample script inline string, and run using `node -e`

```
{
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node -e 'const json = require(\"./package.json\"); json.scripts[\"run:watch\"] = \"npm run watch\";require(\"fs\").writeFileSync(process.cwd() + \"/package.json\", JSON.stringify(json, null, 2))'"
  },
}
```

Comment: Almost what i need. But i would like to copy that script inside the package.json at the root level of the project and not in the one inside the node_modules/my_package.

Is there a way to target this file with the code above? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. If you need to edit root package.json while your module with "postinstall" script is installed as an npm dependency in some consumer project, then you need to lookup in parent directories as long as no package.json resolved

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let rootPath = '../';
while (!fs.existsSync(path.resolve(rootPath, 'package.json'))){
  rootPath += '../';
}
const pkgJsonPath = path.resolve(rootPath, 'package.json');
```